# Proxy module doesn't work when serving nuxt app statically

Tags: node.js, npm, axios, nuxt.js, http-proxy

So, Iv'e been trying to setup a small example of a server with 2 factor authentication features. I'm using `nuxt` as the frontend and `flask` as the backend.

While developing locally (using `npm run dev`) I was able to get the chain of communication to work:

1. The webpage sends a request to `server/<some_request>/<some_param>`
2. The `proxy` module redirects it to `http://localhost:5000/<some_request>/<some_param>`
3. The request is sent by the `axios` module
4. `flask` receives the request, processes it and answers.

When trying to deploy this application to a dreamhost server, I used `npm run build` and `npm run generate` to serve the website statically. I was able to receive my webpage when browsing.

But when trying to login, the chain described above broke, and requests to `server/<some_request>/<some_param>` were answered with 404. In the server's command line I saw that `flask` didn't receive any request, so I assume that this is some issue with the `proxy` module.

I'm not really sure how to debug this problem, so any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got everything working, and here are my conclusions:

1. The `proxy` module, makes the redirection in the client side, meaning that I would be trying to access my own machine when redirecting to `localhost:5000`, rather than to the server.
2. The `proxy` module can't be used when using `npm run generate` (there's a warning that says it's disabled).
3. Since I wanted to redirect to `flask` from the client side (browser), I couldn't just run it as is. I had to register another subdomain and use Passenger to deploy my app ([A guide to enabling passenger](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216385637-How-do-I-enable-Passenger-on-my-domain-), [getting started with python in passenger](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215769548-Passenger-and-Python-WSGI) and [A great guide to deploying flask over passenger](https://www.mattcarrier.com/flask-dreamhost-setup/)).